# Проблема с выводом JSON

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$meteodata = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
echo $meteodata -> sensors[0] -> data[0] -> temp_out;
```

В консоли отображается правильное значение. А на странице браузера - ничего.

Приведение вида `echo (float)$meteodata -> sensors[0] -> data[0] -> temp_out;` дает 0.

Comment: Посмотрите  `print_r($meteodata);` что выведет на экран

Comment: Опять же - в консоли - все, на странице ничего.

Comment: Откуда вы получаете `$url`?

Comment: Формирую сам. И он, при необходимости, выводится на страницу

Comment: Приведите данные, содержащиеся в data[0]

Comment: в консоли это что значит, в браузер вставляете указанную ссылку и смотрите? Проверьте что file_get_contents действительно возвращает json, а то у вас иначе metadata = false и прямой путь к указанию user-agent для начала при запросе данных

Comment: в консоли - это я вызываю компилятор и указываю ему файл

Answer (score -1):

Дело было в PHP. На другом сервере с другой версией PHP - выводит везде